# navigation bar not coming common to both screens

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8.2

[image]

This is my slide menu in cyan color on the left and dark on the right is my actual window having the slide menu. i need a common navigation bar for both of them but i am not getting it.
I have attached my slide menu with a navigation bar "embed in" and which furthure is connected to swrevelviewcontroller. what should i do to get a single top navigation bar in a situation where the slide menu is visible and the screen also.

Comment: set the color of top nav bar to clear color and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to storyboard select view controller then check properties from right side.[image: here, attached screenshot]

Then after you need to set UIBarButton(menu/back) manually in all view controller as per requirement. Might be your problem will solved.